# hostless DNS CNAME record

Tags: dns, centos

We are running BIND 9.9.7 on Centos 6.5 and for a long time I have been creating "hostless" DNS entries so that sites work with or without the www.

Eg:

```
www IN A 192.168.1.1
domain.com.   IN    A 192.168.1.1
```

However, our client wants to use a CNAME record to a cloudfront host and the "hostless" entry doesn't work as a CNAME record.

In fact, it more than doesn't work, BIND won't even load the zone file. The error is 
    "failed: CNAME and other data"

```
domain.com.  IN CNAME host.cloudfront.net.

www IN CNAME host.cloudfront.net.
```

It will load and resolve fine without the domain.com entry. I have tried a few variations, but nothing seems to work. including "*", ".*"

Can anyone tell me the correct syntax for this entry?

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct syntax for this (and it is not BIND specific, it is a side effect of [RFC1912](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt) which states that `A CNAME record is not allowed to coexist with any other data.`

Detailed explanation: [Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain/613830#613830)

Some DNS providers might offer [workaround](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root) [hacks](http://blog.dnsimple.com/2011/11/introducing-alias-record/).