# How to connect my 1and1 domain to OpenShift website?

Tags: dns, openshift, hosting, cname

I have changed the alias in OpenShift to my `www.domain_name.com`.

In 1and1 domain center I am able to write CNAME record only for sub domain. If I do add a CNAME for sub domain will it redirect my original domain to openshift website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `CNAME` for subdomain, it will not redirect your 'original' domain (you probably meant to say "zone apex", "root domain" or "naked domain") to openshift website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dusan , yes I was not able to find , Zone apex in 1&1 domain center but it was easily available in godaddy.com.
I fix this issue by creating sub domain with 'www' in the beginning and then redirect my original domain to this sub domain.
 Is there any improvements i can make ?

Comment: Adding `CNAME` to zone apex is generally not possible (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37149250/1145196) answer).